# How to add annotation in the clicked region of a pdf file in winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, annotations

I want to open a specific pdf file in winform and whenever user clicks on the content of the file it should add annotations on the clicked region. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you already display the pdf?

Comment: Yes i have tried using axAcroPDF and Rasteredge. In axAcroPDF  i can't add annotation. In Rasteredge I can add but It's not possible to find the clicked region.

Comment: I guess you'll need to put some effort into that. You should be able to get a click position from some mouse event handler maybe on the display component. You'll then have to do some maths to translate the mouse coords to a position in the pdf ( taking into account zoom factor, resolution, pdf size ... and page number)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to do by taking those considerations.